# Checkbox toggle with two different properties

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attributes, toggle

I have a list of different entries which all have two properties, attributes to categorize them : `data-one` and `data-two` in my example.

These divs can be **toggled** according to these properties by clicking on **checkboxes**.

I'm however experiencing an issue :

- When clicking on a checkbox for the first time, the divs toggle fine.
- When clicking on a checkbox of the second navigation after the first step, since the command is toggle, all the divs that were toggled with the first click and have the second click attribute are toggled back.

It doesn't make much sense like this but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k9xfo2/62/)'s a simple example to understand better :

```js
/*---- Content of entries ----*/

$(".entry").each(function() {

  var one = $(this).attr("data-one"),
    two = $(this).attr("data-two");

  $(this).html("My data-one is <span>" + one + "</span> and my data-two is <span>" + two + "</span>");
});


/*--- Fix button ---*/

$("button.fix").on("click", function() {
  $(".entry")
    .show()
    .end()
    .not(".shown")
    .addClass("shown");
  $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
});


/*--- Toggle entries ---*/

$(".button[data-one]").on("click", function() {
  var checkBoxes = $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]");
  checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));

  var whichData = $(this).attr("data-one");

  $(".entry")
    .filter("[data-one='" + whichData + "']")
    .slideToggle("slow")
    .toggleClass("shown")
  /*
    .end()
    .filter("[data-one!='" + whichData + "']")
    .not(".shown")
    .hide()
  */
  ;
});

$(".button[data-two]").on("click", function() {
  var checkBoxes = $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]");
  checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));

  var whichData = $(this).attr("data-two");

  $(".entry")
    .filter("[data-two='" + whichData + "']")
    .slideToggle("slow")
    .toggleClass("shown")
  /*
    .end()
    .filter("[data-two!='" + whichData + "']")
    .not(".shown")
    .hide()
  */
  ;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.nav {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: center;
}

.nav label {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #606062;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#474749, #606062);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.button svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 17;
  stroke-dashoffset: 17;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.button+span {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.button {
  background-color: #606062;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#255cd2, #1d52c1);
}

.nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.button svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.entry {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 5px;
}

.entry span {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <header>
    <div class="nav">

      <button class="fix">
    Fix (show everything)
    </button>
      <div class="navigation">

        <h2>Data-one</h2>

        <label for="ex1">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex1" checked>
          <span class="button" data-one="1">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 1</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex2" checked>
          <span class="button" data-one="2">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 2</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex3">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex3" checked>
          <span class="button" data-one="3">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 3</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex4">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex4" checked>
          <span class="button" data-one="4">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 4</span>
        </label>

      </div>


      <div class="navigation">

        <h2>Data-two</h2>

        <label for="ex5">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex5" checked>
          <span class="button" data-two="5">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 5</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex6">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex6" checked>
          <span class="button" data-two="6">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 6</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex7">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex7" checked>
          <span class="button" data-two="7">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 7</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex8">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex8" checked>
          <span class="button" data-two="8">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 8</span>
        </label>

      </div>


    </div>
  </header>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="1" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="3" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="2" data-two="5">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="1" data-two="7">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="1" data-two="5">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="4" data-two="8">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="3" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="2" data-two="7">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="4" data-two="7">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="4" data-two="8">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="3" data-two="5">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="1" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown" data-one="2" data-two="6">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Is there a better way to for example have the two properties in a single dom or maybe using something like [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) (even though i'd rather not...) ?

Comment: I notice that example 7 and 8 have an attribute of 'data-one' although they're in the 'data-two' group.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode Absolutely, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode I edited that. Did you have an idea on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have written some code and will explain how it works:

```js
/*---- Content of entries ----*/

$(".entry").each(function() {
  var one = $(this).attr("data-one"), two = $(this).attr("data-two");
  $(this).html("My data-one is <span>" + one + "</span> and my data-two is <span>" + two + "</span>");
});

/*--- Fix button ---*/

$("button.fix").on("click", function() {
  $(".entry").show().end().not(".shown").addClass("shown");
  $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
});

/*--- Toggle entries ---*/

$("label").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).find(".button").attr("data-one")) {
    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") === true) {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-one='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-one") + "']").addClass("shown");
    } else {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-one='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-one") + "']").removeClass("shown");
    }
  } else {
    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") === true) {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-two='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-two") + "']").addClass("shown2");
    } else {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-two='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-two") + "']").removeClass("shown2");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.nav {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: center;
}

.nav label {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #606062;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#474749, #606062);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.button svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-dasharray: 17;
  stroke-dashoffset: 17;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.button+span {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.button {
  background-color: #606062;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#255cd2, #1d52c1);
}

.nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.button svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.entry {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.entry.shown.shown2 {
  display: block;
}

.entry span {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <header>
    <div class="nav">

      <button class="fix">
    Fix (show everything)
    </button>
      <div class="navigation">

        <h2>Data-one</h2>

        <label for="ex1">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex1" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-one="1">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 1</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex2" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-one="2">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 2</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex3">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex3" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-one="3">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 3</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex4">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex4" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-one="4">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 4</span>
        </label>

      </div>


      <div class="navigation">

        <h2>Data-two</h2>

        <label for="ex5">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex5" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-two="5">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 5</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex6">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex6" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-two="6">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 6</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex7">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex7" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-two="7">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 7</span>
        </label>

        <label for="ex8">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ex8" checked="true">
          <span class="button" data-two="8">
            <svg width="12px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 12 11">
              <polyline points="1 6.29411765 4.5 10 11 1"></polyline>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>Example 8</span>
        </label>

      </div>


    </div>
  </header>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="1" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="3" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="2" data-two="5">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="1" data-two="7">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="1" data-two="5">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="4" data-two="8">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="3" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="2" data-two="7">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="4" data-two="7">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="4" data-two="8">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="3" data-two="5">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="1" data-two="6">
    </div>
    <div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="2" data-two="6">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Firstly, you will need to add a second class to the `.entry` divs (I have added the class `shown2` in my example below and in the snippet):

```
<div class="entry shown shown2" data-one="1" data-two="6"></div>
```

Then add some CSS to hide all `.entry` divs, and another rule to override the previous rule if `.entry` has both the class `.shown` and `.shown2`:

```
.entry {
  ...
  display: none;
}

.entry.shown.shown2 {
  display: block;
}
```

And finally this Javascript to replace your click functions on `.button[data-one]` and `.button[data-two]`:

```
$("label").on("click", function() { //Gets click events on all <label> elements
  if ($(this).find(".button").attr("data-one")) { //If data-one
    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") === true) {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-one='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-one") + "']").addClass("shown");
    } else {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-one='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-one") + "']").removeClass("shown");
    }
  } else { //If data-two
    if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked") === true) {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-two='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-two") + "']").addClass("shown2");
    } else {
      $(".entry").filter("[data-two='" + $(this).find(".button").attr("data-two") + "']").removeClass("shown2");
    }
  }
});
```

Unfortunately this takes away the slide effect, but that can be reproduced somewhat in CSS and I would be willing to walk you through that in a chatroom if that is what you want.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/JamesDouglas/pen/ZVaqYw)